# System to distribute update files

Tags: apache, server, http, ftp

I'm a bit new to the web side of programming.

Can I use Apache for file hosting and recording of clients that download a file?

I need to distribute update files to clients and want to record client ID's when they download them.

Comment: I'm closing this question because I believe it won't lead to constructive answers. The short answer is "yes, Apache can definitely be part of a software stack to do this". The long answer is that I suggest you either search out a recommendation for an off-the-shelf service or software, or get some one-on-one programming help if you're looking to design your own. Unfortunately, both of those paths forward don't fit very well into our Q&A format. If you end up with any specific questions, feel free to ask them here (or Stack Overflow if they are about your code).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your host.  Some hosting services have as one of their Terms and Conditions that their service can't be used as a file bucket.

But if that isn't the case or you have your own server, with adequate coding skills, anything is possible.